# C# Resolving Base Class to Correct Repository Method Call Based on Implemented Type

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, overloading

In our current project, we have an abstract base user class that is implemented by multiple other user types.  We have a comparison class that can compare any of these types and then needs to call a correct update api based on the implemented type.  I am trying to avoid bringing an if(typeof(User)) logic tree into the code and was hoping to figure out some way to solve the issue with method overloading.  Are there any design patterns that can help solve this issue with some type of interface that can be dependency injected?  Here is a basic code example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<BaseUser> TestUsers = new List<BaseUser>();
            TestUsers.Add(new UserA() { Email = "test1@test.com", Location = "New York, NY" });
            TestUsers.Add(new UserB() { Email = "test2@test.com", State = "TN" });

            foreach (var user in TestUsers)
            {
                //need to invoke the correct Print repo method based on the actual user type, possible interface?

            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public abstract class BaseUser
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserA : BaseUser
    {
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }
    public class UserB : BaseUser
    {
        public string State { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserARepo
    {
        void Print(UserA user)
        {
            Console.Write($"User A Saved {user.Email}, {user.Location}");
        }
    }
    public class UserBRepo
    {
        void Print(UserB user)
        {
            Console.Write($"User B Saved {user.Email}, {user.State}");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Print methods only need the Email and Location/State properties of the objects, then change their signature to accept only these two strings.

I would add a common property to the abstract class, which returns the needed property in the User* classes:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    public abstract class BaseUser
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string OtherLocation { get; set;}
    }

    public class UserA : BaseUser
    {
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string OtherLocation {
          get
          {
            return this.Location;
          }
          set
          {
            this.Location = value;
          }
        }
    }
    public class UserB : BaseUser
    {
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string OtherLocation {
          get
          {
            return this.State;
          }
          set
          {
            this.State = value;
          }
        }
    }

    public class UserARepo
    {
        void Print(BaseUser user)
        {
            Console.Write($"User A Saved {user.Email}, {user.OtherLocation}");
        }
    }
    public class UserBRepo
    {
        void Print(BaseUser user)
        {
            Console.Write($"User B Saved {user.Email}, {user.OtherLocation}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the issue in the for loop would still exists in the program main.  It would not know how to  call the correct Print method based on the derived type of base user.  I do agree with this abstraction though.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I'm understanding the problem correctly - but if each of those UserTypes needs an update API or Print Repo method, put them as abstract methods in the class:

```
public abstract class BaseUser
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public abstract void PrintRepo();
}
```

Basically, it's just a question of: what functionality is required of the subclasses if they want to implement your base class?  They have to handle Update requests?  Then put an abstract declaration in the abstract class that says, "Hey, if you inherit from me, you have to include an Update function."

Then your main function becomes something like:

```
foreach (var user in TestUsers)
{
    user.PrintRepo();
}
```